# Question on coverings and and their classifying spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Hello. I have a question on covering spaces. Please let each space be paracompact, path-connected, locally path-connected and semi-locally simply connected.

Let $E\to B$ denote a normal covering space and $G$ its deck transformation group. It is the same as a $G$-principal bundle. On the other hand for a discrete group $G$ a $G$-principal bundle is a normal covering space.

$G$-principal bundles $E\to B$ are in one-to-one correspondence with pointed homotopy classes of maps $[B,BG]$. $BG$ denotes the classifying space construction.

$S^1$ is a classifying space for the integers. There is only one covering of $S^1$ with deck transformation group the integers, the universal covering $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand $\pi_1(S^1)=[S^1,S^1]=\mathbb{Z}$. Can someone explain to me how this fits together? Especially with regard to $\pi_2(S^1)=0$ meaning that $S^2\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not recognized as a covering of $S^2$.

If $G$ is discrete the set $[B,BG]$ should be in a one-to-one correspondence with normal $|G|$-sheeted coverings of $B$. Can one say that $[B,B\pi_1(X)]$ is in a one-to-one correspondence with all normal coverings of $B$?

Thanks.

Comment: You should try this at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should consult your favorite algebraic topology book, and concentrate on the precise statements regarding the Galois correspondence between subgroups of $\pi_1(B,b)$ and connected coverings.  As Sean Tilson remarked, http://math.stackexchange.com is a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The only oversight in your analysis is the statement that $S^1$ has only one covering with group $\mathbb{Z}$. It has only one CONNECTED covering with group $\mathbb Z$. It has plenty of others, such as $S^1\times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But with this reasoning $S^2$ would have non-connected covers such as $S^2\times \mathbb{Z}$, too. How does this fit with $[S^2,S^1]=0$ but $[S^1,S^1]=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: `$S^2\times\mathbb{Z}$` is the only cover of `$S^2$`.  That agrees with the fact that `$[S^2,S^1]$` has only one element, namely 0. 

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Aren't $S^2$, $S^2\times\{1,2\}$, $S^2\times\{1,2,3\}$ all covers of $S^2$?

Comment: @gadwall: They're covers, but not `$|\mathbb{Z}|$`-sheeted ones.  Remember that homotopy classes of maps to $BG$ classify principal $G$-bundles, not any old coverings.